# Regex on two different <class> in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

After a look around i could'nt find any answer that matches my problem...

The fact is i parse an url and get sourcecode, then i want to make a list of dates but those are in two different `<class>` !

if i do this :

```
pattern='<h5 class="preparation|soutenue">(.+?(?=</h5>))'
```

it will return only the content of `<class="soutenue">` and empty values for `<class="preparation">`

*i've trie many other patterns but they will always return me empty list...

If anyone could help would be much appreciated.

Here is the full code if you want to try it out : Python 3.8

```
# coding: utf8
import requests
import re
import pdb
from os import getcwd #getcwd() donne le repertoire courant ou se situe le script
from os.path import *
import os

#PARSING

#Var chemin du dossier "pages"
test_dossier = (getcwd()+"\\pages")

#Boucle pour parser les 6 pages
x=0
while x<=50:
url= 'http://theses.fr/fr/?q=crypto%20monnaies&start='+str(x)
request_headers={'User-Agent': "(Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6" }

req=requests.get(url,headers=request_headers,timeout=10)
content=req.text
#Verification que le dossier existe sinon le crée
if exists(test_dossier):
    with open('pages/theses'+str(x)+'.txt','w', encoding='utf8') as output:
        output.write(content)
else : 
    os.mkdir(test_dossier)
    with open('pages/theses'+str(x)+'.txt','w', encoding='utf8') as output:
        output.write(content)
x+=10

print("Parsing ok !")

#GET DATAS
tab_dates=[]

for j in range(0,51,10):
    with open('pages/theses'+str(j)+'.txt', 'r',encoding='utf8') as output:
        contenu=output.read()

    pattern='<h5 class="preparation|soutenue">(.+?(?=</h5>))'

    result=re.findall(pattern, contenu)
    tab_dates.append(result)

print(tab_dates)
print("datas ok !")
```

Comment: `pattern='<h5 class="(preparation|soutenue)">` - the parentheses around the alternative are necessary/

Comment: You could use the [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) and do it the 'right' way.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use regex to parse html/xml. Look into using a dedicated parser.

Comment: It's an exercise can't use html.parser, beautifulsoup or selenium, i'm just helping my sister, but i'm not found of regex...